# Governor Limits for Asynchronous Methods

Tags: apex, asynchronous, asyncapexjob

I am aware that async apex methods have higher governor limits.

Can someone let me know how "higher" the gov limits for a Async job is ..some kind of numbers or reference link would be great.

If a sync method has 100 SOQL Query limit then what is the SOQL Query limit for asynchronous method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the governor limits in the Salesforce documentation. They have also seperated synchronous and asynchronous limits. In the case of the SOQL query Limit, asynchronous Apex has a limit of 200 queries.

See: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm